# converting unit of measurement in a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3, 4], "unit_measure": ["pound", "gram", "pound", "gram"], "waste": [10,1000,20,1000]})
```

```
id   unit_measure    waste  
1       pound          10       
2       gram         1000
3       pound          20
4       gram         1000
```

I wanna create a new column by converting the gram to lb

```
id   unit_measure   waste   lb_waste
1       pound          10       10
2       gram         1000      2.2  
3       pound          20       20
4       gram         1000      2.2
```

I applied following code:

```py
def lb(df):
  if df['unit_measure'] == 'pound':
    return df.waste
  else:
    return df['waste']*0.0022
df['lb_waste'] = df.apply(lb, axis=1)
```

Which gives me following error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: please provide the code to create the same dataframe

Comment: In your `lb` method, you have `df` as argument but are using `df1` in the function body. Also it'd be better to name the argument as `row` instead of `df`.

Comment: Btw, your data has `pound` but you're comparing with `Pound` (uppercase 'P'). If your code worked correctly, it would use 0.22x on all the rows, not just the ones with pound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your implementation reference the function argument not the global `df1`. Here I've changed the argument name to `row` from `df` to be more clear what it represents ([@Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863071/converting-unit-of-measurement-in-a-data-frame?answertab=votes#comment119949721_67863071) and I were in agreement on this it seems):

```
def lb(row):
    if row['unit_measure'] == 'pound':
        return row['waste']
    else:
        return row['waste'] * 0.0022


df1['lb_waste'] = df1.apply(lb, axis=1)
```

---

However there are a number of more "pandas" approaches that are significantly more performant than the extremely slow `apply`. For example, [@Nk03](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863154/15497888)'s [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) solution.

Or another option via [`Series where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas-series-where):

```
df1['lb_waste'] = df1['waste'].where(df1['unit_measure'].eq('pound'),
                                     df1['waste'] * 0.0022)
```

```
   id unit_measure  waste  lb_waste
0   1        pound     10      10.0
1   2         gram   1000       2.2
2   3        pound     20      20.0
3   4         gram   1000       2.2
```

Comment: Btw, OP's data has `pound` but you're comparing with `Pound` (uppercase 'P'). I'm sure you fixed one of those (code or the dataframe) but it's not obvious - and your code as it is currently, would calculate 0.22x for all the rows.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the `p` in the second option but not the first ( I also copied from the question). Updated now and should work as expected. =)

Answer (score 2):

TRY:

```
import numpy as np
df['lb_waste'] = np.where(df['unit_measure'] == 'pound', df.waste , df['waste']*0.0022)
```